# Is there a difference between calling a member function directly and calling it by its key?

Tags: javascript

I have an async function:

```
async function f() {
   ...
}
```

Also I have object to store functions:

```
const functions = {};
functions['f'] = f;
```

Is there differences between?

```
await f();
```

and:

```
await functions['f']();
```

Comment: Could you explain ***why*** you would think this?  I think that might make this a better question.

Comment: The only difference is the latter requires more keystrokes.

Comment: Thank you everyone, just want to confirm that there are no differences in case of async function

Answer (score 4):

There is a difference in the value of `this`. When calling the function as a method, `this` will be the object it was called on. Otherwise it will be the global object, or `undefined` in strict mode.

```js
(async function() {

async function f() {
  console.log(this === functions);
}

const functions = {};
functions['f'] = f;

await f();

await functions['f']();

})();
```

For further information see [MDN on `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_an_object_method).

To force the context of the "independent" function, you could [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the function to the original object:

```
const f = functions.f.bind(functions);
```

Now, when `f()` is called `this` would always be `functions`.